# Cast needed in subclassed objc array with fixed return type in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, casting

I have a subclass of NSArray, array of labels:

```
@interface LabelArray : NSArray
  - (UILabel*)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
  - (UILabel*)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)index;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
  @property (nonatomic,readonly) LabelArray* labels;
@end
```

When I try to access it from Swift code with 0 index, everything goes fine:

`someObject!.labels[0].textColor = UIColor.redColor()`

But when I use an Index variable

```
var Index: Int = 0
someObject!.labels[Index].textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

xcode gives an error: "Could not find member 'textColor'" and forces me to use an ugly code like this:

```
(someObject!.labels[Index] as! UILabel).textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

I'm subclassing the array to be able to modify a group of labels at once, like `labels.textColor = UIColor.redColor()` will modify each label in array.

What am I doing wrong, and is there a way to avoid this ugly cast?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found an answer.

The problem is in Swift strong typing system.

The argument type in overridden `objectAtIndex:` is Unsigned Integer, and `Index` in the caller procedure was declared as Integer. That's why compiler was considering that Swift Array's `objectAtIndex:` procedure with `Int` argument, returning the AnyObject type, was used.

Bridged declaration looks like this:
`func objectAtIndex(index: Int) -> AnyObject`

The solution is to redeclare `objectAtIndexedSubscript:` with `(NSInteger)index` instead of `NSUInteger`

OR 
to use `UInt()` conversion: `someObject!.labels[UInt(Index)].textColor = ...`

We can also overload the `subscript` property (overload the square brackets operator), but we cannot directly extend the LabelArray, because `subscript` will conflict with obj-c `objectAtIndexedSubscript` method.

Instead, we can declare a protocol, extend it with a new method, and then extend the LabelArray with this protocol:

```
protocol LabelArrayProtocol { }

extension LabelArrayProtocol {
  subscript(index: Int) -> UILabel {
    return (self as! NSArray).objectAtIndex(index) as! UILabel
  }
}

extension LabelArray: LabelArrayProtocol { }
```